# Not able to connect to Kafka on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-kafka

I created an Ubuntu VM on AWS EC2 and in this same VM I'm running one instance of Zookeeper and one instance of Kafka. The Zookeeper and Kafka are running just fine, I was even able to create a topic, however, when I tried to connect from my local machine (macOS) from the terminal I get this message:

```
Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 (ec2-x-x-x-x.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com/x.x.x.x:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

Inside */config/server.properties* I changed the properties **listeners** and **advertised.listeners** (see image below) as I read in many topics related to my issue, but still no way of being able to connect Kafka on EC2 from my local machine:

[image]

I really don't know what I'm missing here...

Kafka version: kafka_2.12-2.2.1

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://PRIVATE_IP_ADDRESS:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS:9092
```

Comment: Can you just telnet the port? Did you enable external traffic to that instance on that port?

Comment: when I telnet the service I get the message: rafaelpaz$ telnet x-x-x-x-x.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com:9092
x-x-x-x-x.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com:9092: nodename nor servname provided, or not known. This stuff is getting really annoying mate LOL! Cheers for the message

Comment: The command should be `telnet x-x-x-x-x.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com 9092` and if you still get an error about a name not found, that would mean your DNS server doesn't know how to reach anything at `amazonaws.com`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After almost 3 days of struggling I was able to find out the problem. In case someone also has the same issue, I solved it by configuring the Security Group on AWS and adding the port 9092 which is the port where Kafka is running by default.
[image]